# Retrieve 1 value from CSV and then add all values to first value, individually without a List

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm developing a Java application in which I store values to a CSV. I need to retrieve one value from one line of a CSV, and then add all values from that line of the CSV including that one to the first value, individually. I need to do that for all values of the CSV. For example:

Suppose one line of my CSV was the following:

```
4
7
11
15
```

I would want to do the following:

```
4+7
4+11
4+15
7+11
7+15
11+15
```

**I could use a List to do this, but I was wondering if any other way existed to do this, as I would not like to put the items into the Heap space** Please note: The solution does not have to use OpenCSV, if there is any way to do this I would be open to hear it. The code I have is below:

```
CSVReader reader = null;
CSVReader reader1 = null;
try {
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("F:\\Bignum\\bignum1.csv"),',', '\'', 1);
    reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("F:\\Bignum\\bignum1.csv"),',', '\'', 1);
    String [] nextLin;

    for (int i = 0; i > 55; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0 + 1; k > 81-i; k++)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear. Can you please reword the question?

Comment: @NickG I tried to clarify it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't want to store anything in memory? The following solution will read values straight from the file, but it'll re-read the file, EVERYTIME it needs to get a value. Warning: This workload (i.e. reading the file) will get exponentially(?) bigger, the more rows you have!

This solution is not using the CSVReader, it's just parsing the csv row using a comma delimiter. You can easily modify this solution to use the CSVReader.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("F:/Bignum/bignum1.csv");
        // get total number of lines
        int totalRows = getTotalRows(file);
        int column = 4;
        for (int a = 0; a < totalRows; a++){
            int aa = getCellValue(file,a,column);
            for (int b = a+1; b < totalRows; b++){
                int bb = getCellValue(file,b,column);
                System.out.println(aa+" + "+bb+" = "+(aa+bb));
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getTotalRows(File file) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int totalLines = 0;
        while (reader.readLine() != null) totalLines++;
        reader.close();  
        return totalLines;
    }

    public static int getCellValue(File file, int row, int column) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int currentLine = 0;
        String line = null;
        while (currentLine++ < row) line = reader.readLine();
        return Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine().split(",")[column]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks great! What do you mean by take a long time? Could you give an estimate?

Comment: No, I can't really give you an estimate, as there will be many variables (i.e. Java version, Operating system, CPU Load, Hard drive speeds (i.e. PC Hardware specs), File size, etc). I'd suggest doing some performance tests of your own! Personally, unless you get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, I'd suggest using my previous solution. Don't be afraid, the Memory is there to be used!

Comment: Are there any speed optimizations that I can make to this?

Comment: Could I run two at the same time? Or more?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you could make speed optimizations. Yes, you can run both  (or more) at the same time.

Comment: Do you have any particular places that you think would be the easiest to optimize?

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("F:/Bignum/bignum1.csv"));
List<Integer> columnValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] row = null;
// read column 5 values into list
while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null){
    columnValues.add(Integer.parseInt(row[4]));
}
Integer[] numberArray = columnValues.toArray(new Integer[columnValues.size()]);
// iterate over array
for (int a = 0; a < numberArray.length; a++){
    for (int b = a+1; b < numberArray.length; b++){
        int aa = numberArray[a];
        int bb = numberArray[b];
        System.out.println(aa+" + "+bb+" = "+(aa+bb));
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
4 + 7 = 11
4 + 11 = 15
4 + 15 = 19
7 + 11 = 18
7 + 15 = 22
11 + 15 = 26
```

Comment: It doesn't really work for me, because I have 5 columns. I only want the last column, and all numbers would be from that.

Comment: Lets be specific, do you mean ',,,,4' (newline) ',,,,7' (newline) ',,,,15' (etc..) ??

Comment: Yeah, 1,2,1,5,thenumberIwant.

Comment: Then how about this? (Where "row[4]" means the fifth column)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: It says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Integer[]` for `Integer[] numberArray = columnValues.toArray();`.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41492/discussion-between-nick-g-and-hichris123)

Comment: Actually, can you think of any way to do this without a List? I have large ammounts of data, and so I don't want to have to put them into heap.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like OpenCSV has only two options, which is to create a String[] by reading a line or to create a List by reading the entire file.I'm not sure why you would have your `for`-loop set up in that manner, as it seems unclear as to what it's supposed to be looking at.

```
    int arr[] = new int[nextLin.length]; //I'm assuming nextLin has your CSV values.

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nextLin.length; i++){ 
       int x = Integer.parseInt(nextLin[i]); 
       for(int j = i+1 ; j < nextLin.length; j++){ 
          System.out.println(x + Integer.parseInt(nextLin[j]));
       }
    }
```

I don't really see a need to do it otherwise unless you would want to do it recursively (which seems unnecessary):

```
    public void mergeAdd(String[] lin, int min, int max){
       if ( max < min ) return;
       // min and max are 0 and lin.length-1 respectively
       if ( min == max ){ //base case
          int x = Integer.parseInt(lin[min]);
          for (int i = min+1; i < lin.length; i++)
             System.out.println(x + Integer.parseInt(lin[i]));
       } else {
          mergeAdd(lin,  min, (min+max)/2);
          mergeAdd(lin,  ((min+max)/2)+ 1, max);
       }
    }
```

Again, I'm not sure why you would want to look for another manner of doing it, but these are just a couple of approaches.

Edit: Fixed a couple things. The output should be correct now. You can change it from `System.out.println` to where-ever you want your output to be.